# render an array in rails, showing only the first record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am rendering an array in this way:

```
    <%@products.to_a.each do |foo|%>
      <th><%= foo %></th>
   <%end%>
```

and give me back the following:

```
<th>{"ID"=>"50538713", "Product"=>"choco", "Stock"=>0}</th>
<th>{"ID"=>"10000750", "Product"=>"pepsi", "Stock"=>0}</th>
<th>{"ID"=>"100538713", "Product"=>"milk", "Stock"=>0}</th>
```

but I only need the first record with only the headings like "ID", "Product", "Stock"

How could I just show the headers?

Comment: What's the value of @products?, there you can set the limit to 1 or to get only the first record. Also `to_a` is not needed if the value of @products is an ActiveRecord_Relation object.

Comment: @sebastian thanks for answer, the value of products is #<ActiveRecord::Result:0x89d5dfd4>, but how can I get the first record?

Comment: Try with `Product.select(:id, :product, :stock).first.attributes.keys`.

Comment: If all you need is column names from a table, why don't you just statically render the column names you know you'll be receiving? – `<th>ID</th><th>Product</th><th>Stock</th>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have said that `@products` is an Array of Hashes, but it may be an empty Array. If it is empty, we need to substitute an empty Hash for the result of `#first`.

Then you can take the first element and get the keys, then iterate over the resulting array:

```
<% (@products.first || {}).keys.each do |key| %>
  <th><%= key %></th>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this works, but when it does not return any value to me I get this error: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass):

Comment: @luis31 See modified answer.